# Flutter:The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to add a google sign in to my flutter application, but the method `googleSignIn` always shows the red squiggly lines. When I hover my mouse over it, it says:

> The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class
>   FirebaseAuth.

What is the solution to this problem?

I have added and imported all the required dependencies.

The dependencies I use are:

```
google_sign_in: ^3.2.4
firebase_auth: ^0.7.0
```

I don't use the latest available dependency versions because of AndroidX Compatibility issue

Comment: Please add the firebase auth and google sign in dependency version that you are using in your pubspec yaml file. Also the flutter sdk version.

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions it works a little differently:

add dependency:

```
google_sign_in: ^4.0.1:
firebase_auth: ^0.8.1
```

After:

final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);
return firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

}

Of course all Firebase settings should be made as given in the lib documentation:
[firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)